# How to declare a method when using late binding

Tags: ms-access, com, vba

I am using late binding to create a MsWord object thus avoiding having to add a reference which would cause problems with different versions of Word.

```
Set GetWordObject = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

Because of this, the VBA compiler does not recognise the MsWord constants and I have been declaring them myself as follows:

```
Public Enum wdAutoFitBehaviour
    wdAutoFitContent = 1
    wdAutoFitFixed = 0
    wdAutoFitWindow = 2
End Enum

Public Enum wdSaveOptions
    wdDoNotSaveChanges = 0
    wdPromptToSaveChanges = -2
    wdSaveChanges = -1
End Enum

Public Enum WdParagraphAlignment
    wdAlignParagraphleft = 0
    wdAlignParagraphCenter = 1
    wdAlignParagraphRight = 2
End Enum

Public Enum WdTableDirection
    wdTableDirectionRtl = 0
    wdTableDirectionLtr = 1
End Enum

Public Enum WdGoToItem
    wdGoToTable = 2
End Enum

Public Enum WdGoToDirection
    wdGoToNext = 2
    wdGoToPrevious = 3
End Enum

Public Enum WdUnits
    wdParagraph = 4
    wdCell = 12
End Enum

Public Enum WdDocumentViewDirection
    wdDocumentViewLtr = 1
    wdDocumentViewRtl = 0
End Enum
```

My problem is when i need to use a MsWord method such as `CentimetersToPoints`:

```
With objWordApp.ActiveDocument.PageSetup
    .TopMargin = CentimetersToPoints(0.5)
    .BottomMargin = CentimetersToPoints(0.5)
    .LeftMargin = CentimetersToPoints(0.5)
    .RightMargin = CentimetersToPoints(0.5)
    .PageWidth = CentimetersToPoints(6.5)
    .PageHeight = CentimetersToPoints(11)
End With
```

How do I declare the method, so that the compiler should not flag it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CentimetersToPoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171811%28v=office.11%29.aspx) is a method of the application object.  Qualify the method name using the name of the application object variable.

```
With objWordApp.ActiveDocument.PageSetup
    .TopMargin = objWordApp.CentimetersToPoints(0.5)
```

Comment: I wonder if the constants that I defined myself (see above) could also be similarly qualified. I see that they belong to enums in the `Word` library, which means I would have to declare each enum as an object? ... not worth my while.